# How to get ClientContext

Tags: office-365

I want to get clientcontext in a visual sandbox webpart.

How can I do it without providing any credentials for url, as webpart will be on home page. I don't want to provide any credentials either, just want it to work like, SPContext.current....

```
string siteURL=”http://localhost“;
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94916/why-code-no-work-in-sandbox-visual-webpart-2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use: ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext, instead of new ClientContext
http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/47576.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try it yet, but i will give you bounty