# Why code no work in sandbox visual webpart 2012

Tags: office-365

This code works in console app but not in sandbox visual webpart built using vvs 2012,

```
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://www.SomeSite.com/sites/test1");
        Web web = context.Web;
        context.Load(web);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        WebCreationInformation WCI = new WebCreationInformation();
        WCI.Title = "Abc3";
        WCI.Language = 1033;
        WCI.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = true;
        WCI.WebTemplate = GetCustomTemplate(web, context).Name;
        WCI.Url = "abc3";


        web.Webs.Add(WCI);

        context.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.WriteLine(web.Id);
```

I get security error on this line,

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://www.SomeSite.com/sites/test1");
```

Comment: Does the web part work without this code? I had a problem in sandbox when the SharePoint 2013 is installed to AD controller.

Comment: it's office 365....

Comment: In office 365 sandbox is configured correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the error because the running of custom code is not supported in sandbox solutions. You will be getting error as 
"Web Part Error: Sandboxed code execution request failed.  This is because of custom code.
It works in console application because you are running the console on your local machine.